# REST API using a RAML specification: how to specify total-pages in response

Tags: rest, api, raml

I am not sure about how the REST API should be designed in terms of pagination.

Here's my example:

```
#%RAML 1.0
title: Test Api Documentation
description: Test Api Documentation
baseUri: https://localhost/
version: v0.1
protocols: [ HTTPS ]
mediaType: [ application/json ]
documentation:
  - title: Test API for REST Client
    content:
      "Test API for REST Client."
types:
  Thing:
    type: object
    properties:
      name: string
      age: number
      color: string
  Things:
    type: object
    properties:
      things?: Thing[]
      totalPages?:
        type: integer
        format: int64
/things:
  get:
    headers:
      Cookie:
        type: string
    responses:
      '200':
        description: OK
        body:
          application/json:
            type: Things
      '401':
        description: Unauthorized
      '404':
        description: Not Found
    queryParameters:
      page:
        description: page
        required: false
        type: integer
        format: int32
      pageSize:
        description: pageSize
        required: false
        type: integer
        format: int32
```

There is this wrapper type 'Things' to be able to add the totalpages property for the response.

Is this the right way how to do it?

I've also read that a custom http header can be used (x-total-pages or something like that).

I actually kind of don't like to have all the wrapper types in the API...
Does anybody know which is the standard for this?

Thanks a lot in advance for your answers.
Sergio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can encapsulate all the paginated traits into a `trait` and use that across all you pageable reosources using `is`. As pageable resource are typically GET /collectionresource, you can also add a trait for the response header X-TOTAL-PAGES for 200 responses that are `paginated`.

Example:

```
#%RAML 1.0
baseUri: https://mocksvc.qax.mulesoft.com/mocks/8ab3d909-11e0-4f1d-aaef-bef029b83fbf
title: paginated api
mediaType: application/json
protocols: [ HTTP ]
traits:
  paginated:
      queryParameters:
        page:
          description: page
          required: false
          type: integer
          format: int32
        pageSize:
          description: pageSize
          required: false
          type: integer
          format: int32    
      responses:
        200:
          headers:
            x-total-pages:  
types:
  Thing:
    type: object
    properties:
      name: string
      age: number
      color: string
  Things:
    type: object
    properties:
      things?: Thing[]

/things:
  get:
    is: [ paginated ]
    responses:
      '200':
        description: OK
        body:
          application/json:
            type: Things
      '401':
        description: Unauthorized
      '404':
        description: Not Found
```

[image: raml2html output]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thx a lot.